# Jquery: Set both "key" and "value" using variance values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two array:

```
var keyname = ["ad","yhc","bf"...."at"]
```

and

```
var keyvalue = ["adf","scv",...."gf"]
```

These two array is in pairs: which means that `keyname[0]` is related to `keyvalue[0]`, and `keyname[n]` is related to `keyvalue[n]`.

Here I want to set a object which may be converted into JS object and made it becoming json format. So I want to create a object like this format:

```
var senddata={some other keys: some other values, keyname[0]:keyname[1],.....}
```

So here I use following methods:

```
for(t=0;t<keyname.length;t++)
      {
          senddata.radioname[t]=""+radiovalue[t];
      }
```

The result is wrong.... the value is OK if I change the key manually into "1,2,3...". But I need to put the values of keyname[] to become the "key" list of the object. How can I do?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Are those `keyname[]` and `keyvalue[]` PHP things?

Comment: No... maybe the way I express is wrong. But I have var keyname= new Array() in the top.

Comment: I've made them array literals now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to set/access dynamic keys of an object

```
var senddata = {};
for (t = 0; t < keyname.length; t++) {
    senddata[keyname[t]] = radiovalue[t];
}
```